# Attempting to dual-boot Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04LTS (UEFI) installed to two separate SSD's

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, windows-7, uefi

I have a home-built system with Ubuntu 14.04LTS installed on a 250GB SSD.  I needed to dual-boot Windows 7, so I got a separate SSD (120GB), and installed it on that (UEFI).  The installation went all the way through, but after the reboot I got a Windows Repair Error screen informing me that Windows couldn't boot due to a hardware or software change.
After beating my head against it for a while, I removed both Windows 7 and Ubuntu, and reinstalled Windows 7 on the 120GB SSD.  Install finished successfully, I was able to log in, install drivers, etc.

Then, I rebooted, popped in the Ubuntu 14.04LTS DVD, booted to that (UEFI), and installed Ubuntu to the 250GB SSD following the instructions [here](http://linuxbsdos.com/2012/07/23/dual-boot-ubuntu-12-04-and-windows-7-on-a-computer-with-2-hard-drives/).

Ubuntu installed successfully, when I rebooted I got the Grub menu, and was able to boot into Ubuntu without any issues.  However, when I selected "Windows Boot Manager" from the Grub menu, I got a black "Windows is loading files" screen, followed by "Windows Repair Error" and two options: System Repair and Start Windows Normally.  System Repair causes the screen to flicker and then goes back to the same two options, Start Windows Normally goes to a "Starting Windows" screen for a second, and then jumps to the Grub menu.

I loaded up the Ubuntu LiveCD, and ran boot-repair, then used "Recommended settings."

Here is the output: http://paste.ubuntu.com/12546127/

In addition to the two SSD's, I also have two NTFS-formatted HDD's used purely for data storage.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: UEFI seems to work better if it is sda, or plugged into first SATA port on motherboard. And you installed Ubuntu to a MBR(msdos) partitioned drive but have it booting in UEFI mode. I have seen that several times before. But UEFI's standard is gpt partitioning. And once you start using UEFI better if drives are gpt. Data drives are not critical. I started converting drives to gpt but booting in BIOS just to have drives converted when I changed to UEFI. Try making Windows first SATA port and  boot from UEFI.  Grub only boots working Windows, so if hibernated or needs chkdsk it will not work.

Comment: There are also BIOS-mode Linux boot loaders installed to `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdc` (SYSLINUX and GRUB). This makes it hard to be sure which mode is booting when you start Ubuntu. (Since you ran Boot Repair from a live CD, nothing can be determined from *its* boot mode.) Please read [my page on BIOS/CSM/legacy mode](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/csm-good-bad-ugly.html) to learn more about this, and why it's become so difficult to figure out what's actually happening on your system. It's best to disable the CSM and stick with EFI-mode booting exclusively.